# How to fetch the list of newly created time entries alone using Postman?

Tags: api-testing, api, postman

From this json, I need to fetch `created_at`. How should I do it in Postman?

```
{
    "meta": {
        "total_logged": 127200,
        "total_logged_per_team_member": [
            {
                "identity_id": 4304617,
                "total_logged": 127200,
                "total_logged_per_client": [
                    {
                        "client_id": null,
                        "total_logged": 7200,
                        "total_logged_per_project": [
                            {
                                "project_id": null,
                                "total_logged": 7200
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "client_id": 92593,
                        "total_logged": 49800,
                        "total_logged_per_project": [
                            {
                                "project_id": null,
                                "total_logged": 49800
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "client_id": 92597,
                        "total_logged": 70200,
                        "total_logged_per_project": [
                            {
                                "project_id": null,
                                "total_logged": 70200
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "total_logged_per_day": [
                    {
                        "date": "2020-08-30",
                        "total_logged": 25200,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": null,
                                "total_logged": 3600
                            },
                            {
                                "client_id": 92593,
                                "total_logged": 21600
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-08-31",
                        "total_logged": 7200,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": 92597,
                                "total_logged": 7200
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-09-01",
                        "total_logged": 28800,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": 92597,
                                "total_logged": 28800
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-09-02",
                        "total_logged": 28800,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": null,
                                "total_logged": 3600
                            },
                            {
                                "client_id": 92593,
                                "total_logged": 10800
                            },
                            {
                                "client_id": 92597,
                                "total_logged": 14400
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-09-03",
                        "total_logged": 32400,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": 92593,
                                "total_logged": 12600
                            },
                            {
                                "client_id": 92597,
                                "total_logged": 19800
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-09-04",
                        "total_logged": 4800,
                        "total_logged_per_client": [
                            {
                                "client_id": 92593,
                                "total_logged": 4800
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "total_logged_per_client": [
            {
                "client_id": null,
                "total_logged": 7200,
                "total_logged_per_team_member": [
                    {
                        "identity_id": 4304617,
                        "total_logged": 7200
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "client_id": 92593,
                "total_logged": 49800,
                "total_logged_per_team_member": [
                    {
                        "identity_id": 4304617,
                        "total_logged": 49800
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "client_id": 92597,
                "total_logged": 70200,
                "total_logged_per_team_member": [
                    {
                        "identity_id": 4304617,
                        "total_logged": 70200
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "total_unbilled": 49800,
        "total": 20,
        "per_page": 20,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 1
    },
    "time_entries": [
        {
            "id": 89044801,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-05T15:04:07Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 89044797,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-05T15:04:00Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 89044775,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-05T15:01:01Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 88585149,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-04T14:57:56Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 88092763,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-04T12:52:46Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 88054605,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-04T12:31:37Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 87885171,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-04T11:16:50Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 87885153,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-04T18:03:28Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-04T11:15:46Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": null,
            "service_id": null,
            "note": "Updated Note",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84957973,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T12:10:57Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:10:56Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11393,
            "service_id": 7183327,
            "note": "Test",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "timer": {
                "id": 12173325,
                "is_running": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 84942719,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T12:05:01Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:05:00Z",
            "client_id": 92597,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11391,
            "service_id": 7181507,
            "note": "Postman",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": true,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "timer": {
                "id": 12173257,
                "is_running": false
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 84942715,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-03T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:04:45Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 12600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942707,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-03T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:04:28Z",
            "client_id": 92597,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": true,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 19800,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942695,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:03:49Z",
            "client_id": 92597,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": true,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 14400,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942689,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:03:34Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 10800,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942683,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:03:19Z",
            "client_id": null,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": false,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": true,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 3600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942669,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-01T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:03:02Z",
            "client_id": 92597,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": true,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 28800,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942661,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-08-31T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:02:42Z",
            "client_id": 92597,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": true,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 7200,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942653,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-08-30T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:02:23Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 21600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942643,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-08-30T18:30:00Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:02:04Z",
            "client_id": null,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": null,
            "active": true,
            "billable": false,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": true,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 3600,
            "timer": null
        },
        {
            "id": 84942613,
            "identity_id": 4304617,
            "is_logged": true,
            "started_at": "2020-09-02T12:00:51Z",
            "created_at": "2020-09-02T12:00:51Z",
            "client_id": 92593,
            "project_id": null,
            "pending_client": null,
            "pending_project": null,
            "pending_task": null,
            "task_id": 11387,
            "service_id": 7181501,
            "note": "Postman",
            "active": true,
            "billable": true,
            "billed": false,
            "internal": false,
            "retainer_id": null,
            "duration": 0,
            "timer": {
                "id": 12173199,
                "is_running": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: here the I need to get using the tag "created_at"

Comment: Welcome. Please format your question next time and include all details in it, not in the comment section. You title says "list", your json object shows there's only one `created_at` attribute. Where are the others? Is this json object everything you get from an endpoint?

Comment: here my json shows only one created at but I need to fetch all the list of current date.

Comment: Bcz my real output is too long where I am unable to paste it here

Comment: Yes this json object is entirely from an endpoint "https://api.freshbooks.com/timetracking/business/4164649/time_entries" from freshbooks app

Comment: The link requires an authorization. I'd be better if you show us how it looks here. I don't mean copying the whole response, but showing 2 - 3 examples of how the data are formed in the response.

Comment: @pavelsaman i have added the entire response. The endpoint url : https://api.freshbooks.com/timetracking/business/4164649/time_entries

Comment: Here I want to fetch only the latest data using the created_at. Everytime I should get the latest/recently created one alone in response. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```javascript
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var x = jsonData.time_entries[0].created_at
```

Use this in test script section.

Comment: able to see "created_at" undefined

Comment: @ShivashankariT is it the full response you given in the question ?

Comment: Yes I have given the full response now

Comment: @ShivashankariT updateed the answer